# Changing the transparency of a program's window(s) whenever I start it

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I am looking for a program that allows me to change the transparency of a program's window(s) whenever I start it.

I know that I can use AHK to [Change Window Transparency in Windows 7 with a Hotkey](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44915/how-to-change-window-transparency-in-windows-7/):

```
; changing window transparencies
#WheelUp::  ; Increments transparency up by 3.375% (with wrap-around)
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
    WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if ! curtrans
        curtrans = 255
    newtrans := curtrans + 8
    if newtrans > 0
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, %newtrans%, A
    }
    else
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
        WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
    }
return

#WheelDown::  ; Increments transparency down by 3.375% (with wrap-around)
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
    WinGet, curtrans, Transparent, A
    if ! curtrans
        curtrans = 255
    newtrans := curtrans - 8
    if newtrans > 0
    {
        WinSet, Transparent, %newtrans%, A
    }
    ;else
    ;{
    ;    WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
    ;    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
    ;}
return

#o::  ; Reset Transparency Settings
    WinSet, Transparent, 255, A
    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
return

#g::  ; Press Win+G to show the current settings of the window under the mouse.
    MouseGetPos,,, MouseWin
    WinGet, Transparent, Transparent, ahk_id %MouseWin%
    ToolTip Translucency:`t%Transparent%`n
    Sleep 2000
    ToolTip
return
```

but I would prefer to have a solution that spares me hitting a shortcut each time the program starts.

If possible:

- free
- works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: you can run an ahk script on program load. see here for more info. http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/40328-run-script-on-program-load/. As long as you know the programs name, you can do this easily

Answer (score 1):

Back in Longhorn times I used "Glass2k" for that: http://chime.tv/products/glass2k.shtml

It remembers the transparency setting for each window which you can configure by right clicking the titlebar (turn on the remember-setting for that).

The downside is the splashscreen at startup which you can't turn off.